# C: converting Farenheit to Celsius

Tags: c, integer-division

```
int main (void)
{
    int fahrenheit; // fahrenheit stands for fahrenheit
    double c; // c stands for celsius

    printf("Enter your fahrenheit, we'll covnvert it into celsius! ");
    scanf("%f", &fahrenheit);

    c = 5/9 * (fahrenheit - 32);
    printf("Here is your %f in celsius!.\n");

    return (0);
}
```

I've followed the code through break points and when it takes in my input the calculations are off, but the formula is correct. Some sort of logic error I can't put my finger on. Please help!

Comment: Try `5.0/9.0` perhaps. `5/9` in integer division is a whopping zero.

Comment: or `(5 * (fahrenheit - 32))/9` if you want to stick with integer math.

Comment: Why not `(fahrenheit - 32)/(1.8)`? :)

Comment: Your `printf()` call doesn't actually provide the variable to print.

Comment: Next time, use a shorter title and indent your code (did this for you). The harder the question is to read, the less people will help

Comment: `scanf` is parsing the number as a `float`, but its actually an `int` and used as such in the calculation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting Fahrenheit to Celsius in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890480/converting-fahrenheit-to-celsius-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `scanf` call uses the wrong format string. You are reading an `int` so you need it to be:

```
scanf("%d", &fahrenheit);
```

---

The expression `5/9` is evaluated using integer division. In fact the compiler can work it out at compile time. That expression evaluates to `0`.

You need to perform floating point division. For instance:

```
5.0/9
```

Or:

```
5/9.0
```

Or

```
5.0/9.0
```

You just need at least one operand to be a floating point value.

Putting this into your expression, you can write:

```
c = 5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32);
```

and obtain the answer that you expect.

---

Your `printf` statement is wrong too. You should enable warnings and let the compiler tell you that. You meant to write:

```
printf("Here is your %f in celsius!.\n", c);
```

Comment: thank you but I caught my error!! thanks again tho really appreciate it.

Comment: If this answer is correct, it should be marked as accepted Victor, even if you caught the error on your own.

Comment: Although the integer division was certainly a problem, `scanf` was being used to read with format `float` into an `int`. Another critical error, and something that would have been obvious with `-Wall`. If you add that to your answer @VictorC really should mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Macattack Sigh. I got two out of three. It's there now.

Answer (score 1):

Integer math versus floating point math.

```
i = 5/9           // i is equal to 0
d = 5.0/9.0       // d is equal to whatever 5 divided by 9 would actually be
```

You also need to actually print the value:

```
printf("Here is your %f in celsius!.\n", c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Operations on integers return integers even if the variable you store the result on is a double. Divisions between integers are truncated.

You should write this instead:

```
c = 5.0/9.0 * (fahrenheit - 32.0);
```

Adding a ".0" (or even just a ".") to your constant makes them floating point values.