# What is difference between F = (9/5 * C) + 32 and F = (C *9/5) + 32 ? Precedence?

Tags: c, operators, operator-precedence

F = (C * 9/5 ) + 32 and F = (9/5 * C) + 32 yield two different results although the input for C is the same. I realize that there is some kind of precedence in operators but i am not sure about it. Does multiplication come before division ?

An input of 20 gives the Fahrenheit value as 68(correct one) in the first case and 52 in the second.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float cel , fahr ; 
    printf("Enter the temperature(C): ");
    scanf("%f",&cel);
    fahr = (9/5 * celt is  ) + 32;
    printf("\nThe temperature in fahranheit is %f ",fahr);

}
```

Expected result is 68 but its 52 for the above code. If I switch the position of '9/5' and 'cel' it gives the correct result. Why is that ?

Comment: What do you get if you use 9.0/5 ? (Also: *Fahrenheit*.)

Comment: That won't compile...

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence should give an idea. (hint: when two operators have the same precedence, in what order are they evaluated?)

Comment: @Geo Mukkath What is "celt is"?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow `is` is a macro that's defined to `==`, but still...

Comment: [C program to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius always prints zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4890480/995714)

Comment: Copy/paste code that you actually tried.

Comment: Use floating point literals (as `9.0/5.0`,  instead of `9/5`)  Integer division `9/5` gives you `1`, while `9.0/5.0` gives you `1.8`.  `(C*9)/5` when `C` is a floating point variable, will convert first `9` to double, then the result (`double`) will be divided by `5.0`.

Answer (score 7):

Multiplication and division have equal precedence in C, and left-to-right associativity.  So,

- `F = (C * 9/5 ) + 32` is equivalent to `F = ((C * 9)/5) + 32`
- `F = (9/5 * C) + 32` is equivalent to `F = ((9/5) * C) + 32`

The two expressions would be algebraically equivalent, except for the fact that C defines `int / int = int`, discarding the remainder.  So, `9/5` is not 1.8 as you might have expected, but 1.

To get a floating-point result from dividing two `int`s, you need to convert at least one of the operands to `float` or `double`.  So instead of `9/5`, write:

- `9.0/5.0`, `9.0/5`, `9/5.0`, or `1.8`, which gives you a `double`, or
- `9.0f/5.0f`, `9.0f/5`, `9/5.0f`, or `1.8f`, which gives you a `float`

Comment: So `F = ((C * 9)/5) + 32` will be more precise than `F = ((9/5) * C) + 32`

Comment: no, the expression: `9/5` results in 1 due to integer truncation of the fraction

Comment: IMHO the best is to use all floating point, as the problem is talking about temperatures: `F = 9.0/5.0 * C + 32.0;`  When converting temperatures it is better to think as a scientist, not as an assembler programmer :)  OMG! this program is the second example of K&R book!!!  Doesn't anybody read it?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, precedence (and integer arithmetic).

They're evaluated like this:

```
F = ((C * 9)/5 ) + 32;
```

vs.

```
F = ((9/5) * C) + 32;
```

The way C does integer arithmetic (it truncates integers towards zero) makes the second incorrect (`9/5` is one).

Instead, use `9.f`, `5.f`, and `32.f`. That way, precedence won't change much (and you'll get correct results).

Answer (score 3):

Besides the precedence problem, the result of `9/5` is `1`.  It would work more like expected if it were written

```
9.0/5       or
9/5.0        or
9.0/5.0       or (even)
1.8
```

Comment: Don't forget the `f` suffix. The OP is dealing with `float`s.

Comment: @JL2210:  the explicit type suffix `f` is not needed except for the pickiest of compilers.  The expression will be evaluated as a `double` and truncated to a `float` on assignment to `fahr`.

Comment: Yes, but in general, try to avoid implicit type changes (they surprise you when you're not paying attention).

Comment: @JL2210 Implicit type conversions are a *feature of the language*.  Avoiding them is silly; doing so denies the utility of using a higher-order language in the first place.  Naturally you have to learn to avoid a few pitfalls (this question demonstrates a dandy one), but I have to disagree with your blanket advice to "avoid implicit type changes".  In general they're fine.

Comment: implicit type conversions can (and often will) result in values other than what the programmer is expecting.   That is why the compiler (when warnings are enabled) outputs a warning message about the problem

Answer (score 3):

This expression

```
C * 9/5
```

is evaluated form left to right because the used operators have the same precedence.

So, it is evaluated like

```
( C * 9 ) / 5
```

Each time when a sub-expression is evaluated the compiler determines the common type of the used operands.

The common type of the sub-expression

```
C * 9
```

is float according to the usual arithmetic conversions. So the result of this sub-expression has the type float and the result of the whole expression

```
( C * 9 ) / 5
```

is correspondingly has the type float.

This expression

```
9/5 * C
```

is evaluated like

```
(9/5) * C
```

As the both operands of the sub-expression

```
9/5
```

are integers then there is used the integer arithmetic and the result of the sub-expression is also integer.

To avoid the dependence of the order of operands you could for example write

```
(9.f/5) * C
```

or

```
(9/5.0f) * C
```

In this case the sub-expressions

```
8.0f/5
```

and

```
8/5.0f
```

are evaluated as an expression with float numbers.

Comment: why everybody insists in using integers, when all the arithmetic mus be done in floats? With this approach, the newcomers to C will believe that using floating point literals is an expensive task.  Nothing further from reality.