# Why (5+10)/2 is 7.0 not 7.5? C programming

Tags: c, integer, double, average, integer-arithmetic

c code :

```
 int main(void) {
 int i = 0, j = 0;
 double avg = 0;
 int *pi, *pj;
 double *pavg;
```

..

```
    pi = &i;
    pj = &j;
    pavg = &avg;
```

..

```
    *pi = 5;
    *pj = 10; 
    *pavg = (*pi + *pj) / 2;
```

here where it prints :

```
    printf("%lf\n\n", avg);
```

it prints `7.000000000`

```
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `(*pi + *pj) / 2;` is an int expression, which produces 7 which is saved to double.

Comment: it's doing an integer division `15 / 2 = 7` and only _then_ casting it to a `double`

Comment: how to cast it to double?

Comment: put 2.0 instead of 2

Comment: We need a canonical dupe for this. It's such an incredibly common FAQ - everyone learning C probably runs into this bug. We have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890480/c-program-to-convert-fahrenheit-to-celsius-always-prints-zero) in the C FAQ but I don't think it's generic enough to use as a dupe target for this.

Comment: I do not understand the point of using pointers here?

Comment: its the assignment

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `(*pi + *pj) / 2`, you are doing integer arithmetic. The numbers after the decimal have already been discarded before you assign to the `double` variable.

One way is to do `(*pi + *pj) / 2.0`. One of the operands of the expression being a double, the other `int`s will be promoted to `double`s before the expression is evaluated.

Another option is to [typecast](https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson11.html) one of the variables to a double `((double)*pi + *pj) / 2`. Here, the de-referencing operator being of higher precedence will be evaluated before the typecast.