# Why doesn't this program give the temperature in Fahrenheit? it just ends after asking for value in Celsius.?

Tags: c

This is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float ce;
    float fh = ((ce*9/5)+32);
    printf("Value of temperature in celcius: ");
    
    scanf("%f",ce);
    printf("value of temperature in farenheit is %f",fh);
    
}
```

The output is
Value of temperature in celcius: 45

it just ends the program after i write the temperature.

Comment: It probably crashes. You need `scanf("%f", &ce);`. Your compiler should have warned you about this.

Comment: you should probably calculate `fh` AFTER you read in `ce`, too

Comment: Apart from the missing `&` also see this newbie FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4890480/c-program-to-convert-fahrenheit-to-celsius-always-prints-zero It should be 5.0/9.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need a `&` before `ce`, and calculate `fh` after you read `ce`

```c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float ce;
    printf("Value of temperature in celcius: ");
    
    scanf("%mf",&ce);
    float fh = ((ce*9/5)+32);
    printf("value of temperature in farenheit is %f",fh);
    
}
```

Try turn on compiler warnings, they should off told you about this.

The reason you need to is if a & is before a variable, it returned the location of that variable in physical memory.

The scarf function overrides the memory at that place, and thus you get the value of your variable in `ce`.

I wrote `%mf` and not `%f` to be [buffer safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow), it's a good habit to get in to.

Comment: `%mf` isn’t a good idea because it doesn’t mean anything when used with `f`.

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much. I just started programming and am learning my first language as c.

Comment: As a response to @Ry- it's still a good habit

Comment: The `m` in `scanf("%mf",&ce);` is not part of the standard C library.  Writing with `m` loses portability.

Comment: Apart from that, uninteresting "missing & in scanf" questions have been answered thousands of times before. Don't answer them - either close as duplicate or close as simple typo.